# как вызвать функцию при измении input или при вводе числа с клавиатуры? jquery

Tags: jquery

```html
<input id="quantity_product" type="number" value="{{$idCountProductsInCart[$product->id]}}" />
```

вот так наверно не правильно

```html
$("#quantity_product").change(function () {
                    
                    alert($(this).val())
                });
                $( "#quantity_product" ).keypress(function() {
                    alert( "Вызвано событие .keypress()" );
                });
```

можно ли  как то чтобы оно типа или это или это
сейчас если стрелкой поменять значение в поле оно сработает на именеие поля а если ввести с клавиатуры и не нажать ентер оно не сработает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#quantity_product").on('input', function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="quantity_product" type="number" value="" />
```